# Phonetic Transcription of Spoken "Whose is it?"

Tags: pronunciation

I do not know how native English speakers *colloquially* pronounce the question "*Whose is it?*". What would the IPA of the sentence be like?
An IPA keyboard is [here](http://ipa.typeit.org/)

**Update:** you could record the sentence in [Forvo](http://www.forvo.com/word-add/Whose%20is%20it?/) if you want to provide a great service to the world! You'll need to open up a free account; it takes just seconds if my memory services me right.

By the way, are American and UK pronunciation the same in this case? I know that in the case of "*is n't it?*" are different.

Comment: Do you mean that you have trouble pronouncing the words individually or, all of them together?

Comment: I do not have any problems with individual words, and I could use a modern dictionary such as Longman's or use the online ones. However, dictionaries do not offer sentence pronunciation.

Comment: There is a dictionary with recordings of individual words being pronounced. *Whose* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/whose_1?q=whose#, *is* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/is?q=is# and *it* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/it_1?q=it#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/hu'zɪzɪt/, with tone rising from /hu/ to /zɪ/ and falling back on /zɪt/.